# Scrollable panel in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i had made a panel with number of buttons in it like this,

```
Ext.define('BeLocal.view.Test', {
       extend: 'Ext.Panel',

       config: {
       fullScreen: true,
       height: 482,
       width: 324,
       scrollable: 'vertical',
       items: [
               {
               xtype: 'button',
               text: 'MyButton1'
               },
               {
               xtype: 'button',
               top: '30%',
               text: 'MyButton2'
               },
               {
               xtype: 'button',
               top: '50%',
               text: 'MyButton3'
               },
               {
               xtype: 'button',
               top: '96%',
               text: 'MyButton4'
               },
               {
               xtype: 'button',
               top: '110%',
               text: 'MyButton5'
               }
               ]
       }

       });
```

i can show only 3 buttons now.
i want this panel scrollable so that i can show all the buttons by scrolling it down, i had set property **scrollable: 'vertical'** , but it doesn't work.
When i remove position of all buttons like **top:50%** scroll works properly, but i want all the buttons on proper position.
how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-top

> top : Number/String
>   The absolute top position of this Component; must be a valid CSS length value, e.g: 300, 100px, 30%, etc. Explicitly setting this value will make this Component become 'floating', which **means its layout will no longer be affected by the Container that it resides in.**

Try setting style config:

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'MyButton1'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        style:'margin-top: 10%;',
        text: 'MyButton2'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        style:'margin-top: 50%;',
        text: 'MyButton3'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        style:'margin-top: 96%;',
        text: 'MyButton4'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        style:'margin-top: 110%;',
        text: 'MyButton5'
    }]
```

Seems to works for me.

Comment: what i have to do add more than one style ?
like i want to set margin-top and margin-left in single style..

Comment: @master style:'margin-top: 10%; margin-left:20%;',